# Styling Android App Template

Tags: android, styles

My company downloaded the SmartJobBoard app for Android and iPhone (https://www.smartjobboard.com/android_app/). This app came with it's own styling (i.e. orange color). We are looking to make a few changes to the color.

I am from a web development background, and was wondering how would I go about stylizing the colors? Do I have to download the entire APK, change the colors, then re-upload it? Or is there a way to do it by changing the style document and having it go live immediately?

Apologies for being so new at this. I did a lot of reading but my situation seems pretty specific since I already have the app developed!

Thank you!

Comment: Colors are found either in the `layout files (*.xml)`, in the `themes/styles`, in the `colors.xml` file or in separate `image resources` (often 9 patches, which are a particulare type of png). And in `xml drawables` as well. Without knowing the application, it's hard to tell what to change. You have to analyze it deeply and then change the colors as per your tastes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I access these files? The app I am working with was developed and published by a third party. Is there a way to access the files through FTP? Or do I have to download all the source files, change them, save it, then reupload it, and publish it on Google Play?

Comment: The second is the way. Get the source, download. modify, compile them and republish the app.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you feared, it's the hardest way... ;)